# What do I do with this 800kb javascript file?

Tags: javascript, performance, gzip, minify

I read that concatenating and possibly gzipping a javascript file will make an application run faster, so I decided to give it a go.

I figured most of my pages (although not all) were downloading at least 1mb of javascript, so why not compress and aggregate it?

Well, it turns out I think the performance is worse than before. Firebug is reporting that the "DomContentLoaded" took 1.17s on any random page for the application. Is this at normal? Like whoa.

Basically my application javascript now aggregates all of the files for the site. Each file looks for a main id, and if it's there, it runs some code. If not, it just goes the next function block.

I have put in a bunch of libraries along with my application code as well. Here are the libraries I'm using. Should I have aggregated these, or no?

```
<include>**/font/font.js</include>
<include>**/json/json2.js</include>
<include>**/jwplayer/jwplayer.js</include>
<include>**/underscore/underscore.js</include>
<include>**/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js</include>
<include>**/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js</include>
<include>**/jquery/jquery.cookie.js</include>
<include>**/jquery/jquery.jcrop.js</include>
<include>**/jquery/jquery.tmpl.js</include>
<include>**/jquery/farbtastic.js</include>
<include>**/simpleyui/simpleyui.js</include>
<include>**/audio-player/audio-player.js</include>
<include>**/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js</include>
<include>**/jscharts/jscharts.js</include>
```

I think my big footprint is in `jquery-1.7.1.js` (100k), `jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js` (206k), `jwplayer.js` (83k), `simpleyui.js` (103k), `jscharts.js` (100k) and `tiny_mce.js` (186k). Those kb amounts are minified surprisingly.

I've experimented with gzipping the content on demand, but this actually makes it slower. I guess rackspace cloud's cpus are not very fast? It adds a lot of time to the request. Turning off gzipping on demand seems to make things better.

**EDIT:** I can confirm that putting the javascript at the bottom of the page makes no difference. I can confirm that removing all of the libraries like jquery, audio-player, jwplayer, etc. takes a total of 1 seconds just by itself.

My application code (which is a lot more files, but less code overall probably) takes about .2 to .3 seconds.

I am 99% sure the problem has nothing to do with downloading now and a lot more to do with execution speed.

What would you recommend I do to improve the performance of my pages?

Comment: do you have to have all these javascripts load at the same time? do you need all of them for 1 page? put them at the end of the page, and asynchronously load them in parallel.

Comment: 1MB of JavaScript is a silly amount. Also, 1.17s for a page to load is tiny. I don't really see the problem here.

Comment: Isn't there a jQuery plugin for this sort of thing???? ......

Comment: Do you need each one of those JS libraries immediately when the page loads? If not, let the page build and then add your JS downloads at the end, near the bottom of the file. Looks to me as though they all should be minified already, right? You might also want to consider looking up JS file loading, along the lines of dynamically loading external JS files: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/ OR using AMD loaders as described at http://unscriptable.com/code/Using-AMD-loaders/#0

Comment: @ShawnSpencer The nczonline article seems to make a big difference, especially in chrome. In firefox, it renders in about 60% of the time. In chrome, it appears to render in 10% of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load **only the javascript libraries you need on each page**.

In my current project we are working on reducing reliance on outside javascritpt library dependencies by encapsulating components of functionality and passing them through a dependency manager that loads only the javascript libraries that are needed for each particular page (if a page has 3 modules then it only loads the libraries needed for those).

You can use this approach to get rid of a lot of needless requests for particular libraries.

**Reduce reliance on outside libraries as much as possible.**

In addition, we've taken measures to reduce reliance even on jQuery by converting our code to use DOM directly instead, for example by using `document.getElementByID()` and `getElementsByTagName()` instead of `jQuery('#myId')` or `jQuery('table.myTableClass')`. This has helped cut down some pages so that they use no dependencies at all, hence giving an incredible boost to their loading time.

Another example is that if you only need CSS selectors instead of the whole gamut of jQuery functionality you can use [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) which is the standalone CSS selector engine, thus cutting your 80+ KB of jQuery into only 4KB needed for Sizzle. I'm sure the same approach can be used with your other libraries to trim down a lot of unnecessary flab in your application.

Comment: If you load the scripts at the bottom of the page does it really matter how many are there? (To a certain extent)

Comment: Yeah, I think all of this advice is good in combination with the advice given by Shawn Spencer in the comments section below the question. How do deal with the development/production environment problem? I am using java, so it's not easy to work with minified/aggregated versions of javascript in development without packing a war file for example.

Comment: @Nick I don't think loading at the bottom of the page makes that much difference anymore - maybe in older browsers possibly, but I doubt it would make a big difference in new browsers. Some scripts won't even work properly if you don't put them in the header. I tested this though - makes zero difference in performance for me. I think Steven and Shawn's advice look to be the best.

Answer (score 3):

I always load libraries from a trusted cdn like google cdn. This will help you to cache those. This helps parallel downloading also since its from a different domain than yours

Comment: This was good idea. It turns out, this isn't the real problem. I am pretty sure that the problem is blocking or executing speed of the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I created a class that JSMin everything and put's it in one file so that it requests only one file, and not many, as too much files will slow down the page.

So basically the process is:

- Read all files
- Add up all the content together
- JSMin (I used this: https://github.com/rgrove/jsmin-php/)
- Gzip if you want (I didn't, didn't see a performance gain as PHP is usually set to gzip content automatically)
- Cache the file on the disk so that you don't have to do all this again

-EDIT- Found the article I used: http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/supercharging-javascript-part-1-make-as.html

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing all of that except that I'm using YUICompressor instead of JSMin. I have tried gzip, but it's slowing it down for some reason. I'll read that article at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are static files, I recommend you test gzipping the files in advance. gzipping the files will actually use a lot of cpu, but if you do it in advance, then you only pay that cost  when you generate the files.

There is still the possibility that unzipping the files on the client side will be slower than you'd like, so make sure and test that.

As for how to tell your server to serve the gzipped version when necessary, I'm not sure how backspace does it, but on my hosting environment, I use the suffix "html.en" for non-gzipped files and the suffix "html.en.gz." The Apache server is able to use the appropriate file depending on the headers.

Comment: I can tell yuicompressor to make gzip copies of these aggregated files in advance. How do include the gzip'd versions in my html code? I've never done this before.